# Using $_has_many in Kohana's ORM model

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-3, has-many

So I'm trying to learn Kohana, and I've hit quite a snag when it comes to their ORM module. **When trying to set up a one-to-many ORM object, I am able to update/insert the information from my parent model, but it won't allow me to associate ( insert/update ) any new children.**

For clarity's sake, here is my database structure...

```
recipes
--id
--recipe
--directions
--servings

ingredients
--id
--recipe_id
--amount
--serving

items
--id
--item
```

**...my models...**

```
class Model_Recipe extends ORM
{
    protected $_has_many = array( 'ingredient' => array() );
}

class Model_Ingredient extends ORM
{
    protected $_belongs_to = array( 'recipe' => array() );
    protected $_has_one = array( 'item' => array() );
}

class Model_Item extends ORM
{
    protected $_belongs_to = array( 'ingredient' => array() );
}
```

**...and my controller...**

```
class Controller_Recipe extends Controller
{
    function action_save_form()
    {
        $recipe = ORM::factory( 'recipe', 1 );  

        $recipe->ingredient->recipe_id = 1;
        $recipe->ingredient->amount = 1;
        $recipe->ingredient->measurement_type = 'tablespoon';
        $recipe->ingredient->save();

        $recipe->ingredient->item->item = 'butter';
        $recipe->ingredient->item->ingredient_id = $recipe->ingredient->id;
        $recipe->ingredient->item->save();
    }

}
```

I freely admit this is due to my ineptitude, but I've been over the docs/wiki/read(ing) through the source code, and haven't been able to find anything even close. Appreciate any help/ideas everyone may have

EDIT: After re-reading, it may not be very clear. What I am trying to do, is update the $recipe object, and then update/add ingredients, and their one-to-one sub-objects ( items ) like so:

Comment: If it helps, I'm using Kohana 3.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Austin pointed out, has many relations should be plural by convention.

Another thing you're missing is filling has many relations with data; there is no sense in doing it the way you're trying but rather:

```
function action_save_form()
{
    $recipe = ORM::factory('recipe', 1);

    // Create an ingredient and attach it to the recipe (one-to-many)
    $ingredient = ORM::factory('ingredient')->values(array(
        'amount'            => 1,
        'measurement_type'  => 'tablespoon',
        'recipe'            => $recipe, // sets the fk
    ));

    $ingredient->create();

    // Update all ingredients?
    foreach ($recipe->ingredients->find_all() as $ingredient)
    {
        $ingredient->amount = 2;
        $ingredient->update();
    }

    // Create an item and attach to the recipe (one-to-one)
    $item = ORM::factory('item')->values(array(
        'item'          => 'butter',
        'ingredient'    => $ingredient,
    ));

    $item->create();

    // Update the recipes' item after it's been created
    $ingredient->item->item = 'chocolate';
    $ingredient->item->update();
}
```

Note: this example doesn't catch ORM_Validation_Exceptions, which should be performed in order to get validation errors.

Comment: Just a note - your code is for Kohana v3.1.x (use `save()` method instead of `create()` and `update()` for 3.0.x)

Comment: @biakaveron thanks for making that clear, he already specified that he's using 3.1.2

Answer (score 3):

For $_has_many, you should pluralize.

Instead of:

`protected $_has_many = array( 'ingredient' => array() );`

try:

`protected $_has_many = array( 'ingredients' => array() );`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, thats for Kohana-2, not Kohana-3 (what I'm using)

Comment: Nope -- KO3 is still using the Inflector class to use singular/plural forms in the appropriate places to make the code read more like the way you'd say it in natural language.  Personally, I really appreciate this feature.  See http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany